# How to display rows in nested format when matches multiple rows with linking table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1: Income

```
st_id, st_date,  st_sl, income_amount
-------------------------------------
12   11/11/2018   1    100
12   11/11/2018   2    10
13   11/11/2018   1    50
```

Table 2: Util

```
util_date, serial_no, st_id, st_date, st_sl, util_amount
----------------------------------------------------------
12/11/2018     1       12    11/11/2018  1    20
12/11/2018     2       12    11/11/2018  1    50
13/11/2018     1       12    11/11/2018  1    30
12/11/2018     1       13    11/11/2018  1    50
```

I want the result as:

```
st_id, st_date,  st_sl, income_amount, util_date, util_amount
---------------------------------------------------------------
12      11/11/2018   1        100        12/11/2018     20
                                         12/11/2018     50
                                         12/11/2018     30
12      11/11/2018   2         10           null       null
13      11/11/2018   1         50        12/11/2018     50
```

I want a single row from table 1 when the linking table has multiple rows matching. like above.

What could be query to achieve this type of result? Please help.

The below query is normal sql query for linking 2 tables. It gives duplicate like records from Income table (Means single row repeats due to the Income table ref present in two rows in Util table). But I want single row from Income table & multiple rows from Util table like above example.

```
select st_id, st_date, st_sl, income_amount, util_date, util_amount
  from income i, util u
 where i.st_id = u.st_id
   and i.st_date = u.st_date
   and i.st_sl = u.st_sl;
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: can you add the query to the quesion?

Comment: "I want a single row from table 1 when the linking table has multiple rows matching."  Your sample data has three rows for the first matching row.  Hence, I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Exactly. The first row of income table is matching with 3 rows in util table. But in the output the income table column should be displayed once & util table values should be displayed in 3 rows. ( Income table values suppressed in 2nd & 3rd rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct query to show the data you want should be

```
select st_id, st_date, st_sl, income_amount, util_date, util_amount
  from income i 
  left join util u on 
         i.st_id = u.st_id
     and i.st_date = u.st_date
     and i.st_sl = u.st_sl;
```

Please note the left in the join condition.

But you want that "duplicate" income rows to be suppressed to a single row.
This can be done in multiple ways but one ideea would be:

```
select case when util.serial_no = 1 then i.st_id end as st_id, 
       case when util.serial_no = 1 then i.st_date end as st_date, 
       case when util.serial_no = 1 then i.st_sl end as st_sl, 
       income_amount, 
       util_date, 
       util_amount
  from income i 
  left join util u on 
         i.st_id = u.st_id
     and i.st_date = u.st_date
     and i.st_sl = u.st_sl;
```

> UPDATE1:

As the sample data and explanation changed, another query to comply with the request would be:

```
select 
  case when row_number() over (partition by i.st_id, i.st_sl, u.util_date order by u.serial_no) = 1 
     then i.st_id 
  end as st_id, 
  case when row_number() over (partition by i.st_id, i.st_sl, u.util_date order by u.serial_no) = 1 
     then i.st_date 
  end as st_date, 
  case when row_number() over (partition by i.st_id, i.st_sl, u.util_date order by u.serial_no) = 1 
     then i.st_sl 
  end as st_sl, 
  i.income_amount, 
  u.util_date, 
  u.serial_no,
  u.util_amount
from income i 
left join util u on 
         i.st_id = u.st_id
     and i.st_date = u.st_date
     and i.st_sl = u.st_sl;
```

So, the first three columns get values only for the first rows in the group of std_id, st_sl, util_date.

See a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d165/9) for demonstration. (also it would be really nice if you give a fiddle with test data in the question next time.)

Comment: If the part income amount is utilized on different days, then the util.serial_no will be 1 on 12/11/2018 & again 1 for 13/11/2018.  Ex: See the util table 3rd row, this was happened on the same day (12/11/2018) hence i got the util.serial no as 3. In case this utilization is done on next day, again i'll get the util.serial no as 1 & util_date as 13/11/2018. So above query again gives me a "duplicate" rows!!! Is it possible to get output without hard coding like serial_no?

Comment: I don't get it. My code gives the desired output for the given input in the question? Do you have another case that my query doesn't match the request? pls edit the question with that edge case. I don't know what serial no and utilization are, I just gave the query for given input.

Comment: I've modified the Util table data. Now you can check. The first row from Income table coming twice from your code.

Comment: Ah, ok, you've changed the test data. I'll come back with a possible query.

Comment: Forin Ghita, thanks for answering, It works very well for my requirement.